# How to keep all key columns in Dataframe join

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

**Inputs**

I have these two dataframes

```
current_rComp =

            #1     X    Y
0  nationality  BART  USA


next_rComp=
    
             #2     X        Z
0   nationality  BART      USA
1  placeOfBirth  BART  NEWYORK
2     hasFather  BART   HOMMER
```

I need to inner join 2 dataframes using the same key(`X`). So I tried as below.

```
key = current_rComp.columns.intersection(next_rComp.columns).tolist() 
proof_path = pd.merge(current_rComp, next_rComp, on=key)

proof_path =

            #1     X    Y            #2        Z
0  nationality  BART  USA   nationality      USA
1  nationality  BART  USA  placeOfBirth  NEWYORK
2  nationality  BART  USA     hasFather   HOMMER
```

but I wonder if there is a way to keep both of the join key columns when joining the two pandas dataframes. Is there a simple way to maintain all the columns used as join keys?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with filtered columns by `key` list:

```
key = current_rComp.columns.intersection(next_rComp.columns).tolist() 
proof_path = pd.merge(current_rComp, next_rComp, on=key)

df = pd.concat([proof_path, proof_path[key]], axis=1)
print (df)
            #1     X    Y            #2        Z     X
0  nationality  BART  USA   nationality      USA  BART
1  nationality  BART  USA  placeOfBirth  NEWYORK  BART
2  nationality  BART  USA     hasFather   HOMMER  BART
```

But not recommneded, if need processing DataFrame later, because if select column with duplicated column name get all columns like:

```
print (df['X'])
      X     X
0  BART  BART
1  BART  BART
2  BART  BART
```

If unique column name output is `Series`:

```
print (df['Y'])
0    USA
1    USA
2    USA
Name: Y, dtype: object
```